# call a function when value is changed javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi i want to call the function when the value changes

```
   <script>

function calculom(cantidad,promedio,inputtext,inputtextt){
    // Calculo del subtotal
    subtotal = promedio*cantidad;
    subtotall = promedio*cantidad;
    inputtext.value=subtotal;
    inputtextt.value=subtotall;

}

function calculos(cantidad,promedio,inputtext){

    // Calculo del subtotal
    subtotal = promedio+cantidad;
    inputtext.value=subtotal;
}

        </script>
```

and the  html

```
<div id="form-signin">
                    <input type="text" id="platanos" placeholder="Cantidad" onChange="calculom(this.value,precioplatanos.value,totalplatanos,totalplatanos4);">
                    <input type="text" id="precioplatanos" placeholder="Promedio" onChange="calculom(this.value,platanos.value,totalplatanos,totalplatanos4);"/> 
                    <input type="text" size="8" id="totalplatanos" name="tot" placeholder="Derp">
                    <hr>
                    <input type="text" id="platanos2" placeholder="Cantidad" onChange="calculom(this.value,precioplatanos2.value,totalplatanos2,totalplatanos5);">
                    <input type="text" id="precioplatanos2" placeholder="Promedio" onChange="calculom(this.value,platanos2.value,totalplatanos2,totalplatanos5);"/> 
                    <input type="text" size="8" id="totalplatanos2" name="tot2" placeholder="Derp" onclick="calculos(this.value,totalplatanos.value,totalplatanos3);">
                    <hr>
                    <input type="text" size="8" id="totalplatanos3" placeholder="Subtotal">
```

but its not working this line:

```
<input type="text" size="8" id="totalplatanos2" name="tot2" placeholder="Derp" onchange="calculos(this.value,totalplatanos.value,totalplatanos3);">
```

at least if i made a change manually in that input the value changes fine
i want to make it automatic

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're asking. Can you say clearly when it *does* work and when it *doesn't*?

Comment: i want to call calculosfunction when totalplatanos2  and totalplatanos id changes

Comment: @jtaco263 could you make fiddle for this?

Comment: @jtaco263: Changes ***how***? When the *user* changes it via the browser? When you set its `value` property?

Comment: when value in textbox changes ? you need to use `onkeyup` or similar approaches

Comment: when you fill platanos,precioplatanos,platanos2 and precioplatanos2 inputs they call the calculom function who autofills totalplatanos2 and totalplatanos inputs then i want totalplatanos2 and totalplatanos filled inputs call calculos function

Comment: just replace `onChange` to `onkeyup`. also explain what you are trying to do in javascript?

Comment: i want to sum derp´s inputs automatically after cantidad and promedio procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think this is what you want to do,
Your HTML code should be like this, you should use `onkeyup` instead of `onChange` also you were passing id which is not defined like `totalplatanos5` `totalplatanos4`,

```
<div id="form-signin">

<input type="text" id="platanos" placeholder="Cantidad" onkeyup="calculom(this.value,precioplatanos.value);">
<input type="text" id="precioplatanos" placeholder="Promedio" onkeyup="calculom(this.value,platanos.value,totalplatanos);"/> 
<input type="text" size="8" id="totalplatanos" name="tot" placeholder="Derp">
<hr>

<input type="text" id="platanos2" placeholder="Cantidad" onkeyup="calculom(this.value,precioplatanos2.value,totalplatanos2);">
<input type="text" id="precioplatanos2" placeholder="Promedio" onkeyup="calculos(this.value,platanos2.value,totalplatanos2,totalplatanos.value,totalplatanos3);"/> 
<input type="text" size="8" id="totalplatanos2" name="tot2" placeholder="Derp" />

<hr>

<input type="text" size="8" id="totalplatanos3" placeholder="Subtotal" />

</div>
```

your `JavaScript`

```
    function calculom(cantidad,promedio,inputtext){
        // Calculo del subtotal
        subtotal = promedio*cantidad;
        inputtext.value=subtotal;
    }

    function calculos(cantidad,promedio,inputtext,drp1,total){
    subtotal = promedio*cantidad;
    derp2.value=subtotal;
    // Calculo del subtotal
  sum = Number(subtotal)+Number(derp1);
  total.value=sum;
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3ppar8ms/1/)

Comment: exactly as i want but i want to sum derp's inputs automaticly